# Set Three.js scene into a jQuery modal window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, three.js

I try to insert a Three.js scene into a jQuery modal window. The goal is to use the Three.js scene with bigger dimensions, i.e in a bigger window. This scene is expected to appear after clicking on an image which represents the scene but with a smaller dimension.

Right now, you can see an example of what I have managed to do: [on this link](http://beulu.com/last/index6.html)

As you can see, I have a centered image and if a mouse is over it and click it, the expected result is to have the Three.js scene into a modal window.

But, as you can test it, if I click, things are totally wrong (a scene window appears at the top-left, in addition to the image ...)

I explain what I did (see JavaScript source [HERE](http://beulu.com/last/js/sphere_dev.js)) :

When user is over image and click it (`imageElement` DOM), I call the following part of code (which is inspired from a standard jQuery modal window code) :

```
imageElement.onclick = function RaiseWindow() {                                          
      
      var popID = 'canvas'; // Find the pop-up                                           
      var popWidth = 700; // Width                                                  
      
      // Make appear pop-up and add closing button
      $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': popWidth}).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="../close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');                                                                                        
                                                                                         
      // Get margin to center window - adjust with 80px                                  
      var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;                               
      var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;                               
                                                                                         
      // Apply Margin to Popup                                                           
      $('#' + popID).css({                                                               
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,                                                      
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft                                                     
        });                                                                              
                                                                                         
      // Display background                                                              
      $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');                                         
      $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'contrast(0.3)'}).fadeIn();                             
                                                                                         
      return false;                                                                      
    };
```

The container (div) for `id canvas` is got by doing :

```
// Div container for canvas                                                              
container = document.getElementById('canvas');                                                                                                     
container.style.display = 'none';                                                                   
                                                                                         
// Initiate WebGLRenderer renderer                                                       
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });                                                                                         
renderer.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);                                           
renderer.sortObjects = true;                                                             
// AppendChild renderer to container                             
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
```

Initially, I did `container.style.display = 'none';` because otherwise, the scene is drawn whereas I have not clicked on the image.

In HTML source, I have done :

```
<td class="body_content"><br>
    <!-- WebGL into td body_content -->
    <div id="canvas" class="center"></div>
    <!-- Javascript -->                                                                  
    <script src="js/sphere_dev.js"></script>                                                                                     
</td>
```

Currently, the modal window is not displayed when I click and I don't understand why. Then, after this first issue, Surely I will have to remove `container.style.display = 'none';` but I can't do this firstly (Three.js will appear and the image too).

How can I display firstly the modal window and after the Three.js scene into this window.

### Update 1

I have progressed. I manage to grey full window but the popup is not displayed.

In the HTML code, I did :

```
    <!-- WebGL into td body_content -->
    <div id="canvas" data-width="500" data-rel="popup_webgl" class="center"></div>
    <!-- HTML content of popup_webgl -->
    <div id="popup_webgl" class="popup_block">
    <p>Aliquip transverbero loquor esse ille vulputate exerci veniam fatua eros similis illum valde. Praesent, venio conventio rusticus antehabeo lenis. Melior pertineo feugait, praesent hos rusticus et haero facilisis abluo. </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="js/sphere_dev.js"></script>
```

Into sphere_dev.js code, Here what I did (at the beginning, I get back `rel` and `width` variables, and after I use `fadeIn`) :

```
imageElement.onclick = function RaiseWindow() {

    var popID = $(this).data('rel'); // Get name of pop-up
    var popWidth = $(this).data('width'); // Get width

    // Make appear pop-up and add closing button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': popWidth}).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="./close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    // Get margin to center window - adjust with 80px
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    // Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({
      'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
      'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
      });

    // Display background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'contrast(0.8)'}).fadeIn();

    return false;
};

//Close Popups and Fade Layer
$('body').on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function() { // When click body
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#fade, a.close').remove();
      }); // They disappear

    return false;
    });
```

You can check the last results on [this link](http://beulu.com/last/index7.html).

Why is the popup not displayed even if full window is grey after clicking.

### Update 2

Following the different answers, I can get to display the Three.js scene but an issue of centering is occurring.

You can check the last results on [this link](http://beulu.com/last/index8.html)

As you can see, if you click on image to display popup, you get this (on Firefox and Chrome) :

[image: Capture of popup]

The issue is that popup is not centered (slightly shifted horizontally to the right and vertical margin on top too high, and finally bottom of popup not visible).

I tried to center it by doing (`mainWidth` and `mainHeight` are global variables) :

```
// Keep good proportions for popup (from image (width=900, height=490))
// For popup, set 90% of available width and compute height from this value :
var mainWidth = 0.9*window.innerWidth,
    mainHeight = mainWidth*(490/900);


imageElement.onclick = function RaiseWindow() {

    var popWidth = mainWidth;
    var popHeight = mainHeight;
    var xPop = (window.innerWidth/2) - (popWidth/2);
    var yPop = (window.innerHeight/2) - (popHeight/2);    

    console.log('print popWidth = ', popWidth);
    console.log('print popHeight = ', popHeight);

    // window.offsetHeight not working
    //console.log('window.offsetHeight = ', window.offsetHeight);

    console.log('print x = ', xPop);
    console.log('print y = ', yPop);

    // Make appear pop-up and add closing button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({'position': 'fixed', 'width': popWidth+'px', 'height': popHeight+'px', 'top': xPop+'px', 'left': yPop+'px'}).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="./close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    // Display background
    $('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
    // Working only for background
    $('#fade').css({'filter' : 'contrast(0.8)'}).fadeIn();

    return false;
};
```

I have to make you notice that function `window.offsetHeight` doesn't work on Firefox and Chrome, instead of this, I have to use `window.innerHeight`.

Here's the CSS I used for this popup :

```
.popup_block{
display: none; /* masked by default */
background: #fff;
padding: 20px;
border: 20px solid #ddd;
font-size: 1.2em;
position: fixed;
z-index: 99999;
/*--Les différentes définitions de Box Shadow en CSS3--*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #000;
/*--Coins arrondis en CSS3--*/
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

The entire CSS is available on [this link](http://beulu.com/last/style/style_popup.css).

How can I fix this issue of centering.

Comment: First thing I think you should do is get the modal working correctly without the three.js scene because it seems like it is just an issue with positioning to me.

Comment: thanks, I am going to look at this part of my issue

Comment: -@2pha Could you take a look please at my **UPDATE 1** above where I can get to grey window but not to display popup window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with the code you already have, you can just move your canvas element inside the popup `div#fade` block and then instead of destroying it on body click, hide it by just leaving `fadeOut` on the `a.close, body` click event. Try to change the image click event to be like this:

```
$('#contrast').get(0).onclick = function RaiseWindow() {
//$('a.poplight').on('click', function() {

    var popID = $(this).data('rel'); // Get name of pop-up
    var popWidth = $(this).data('width'); // Get width

    // Make appear pop-up and add closing button
    $('#' + popID).fadeIn().css({ 'width': popWidth}).prepend('<a href="#" class="close"><img src="./close_pop.png" class="btn_close" title="Close Window" alt="Close" /></a>');

    // Get margin to center window - adjust with 80px
    var popMargTop = ($('#' + popID).height() + 80) / 2;
    var popMargLeft = ($('#' + popID).width() + 80) / 2;

    // Apply Margin to Popup
    $('#' + popID).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
        });

    // Display background
    //$('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');
    //$('#fade').css({'filter' : 'contrast(0.8)'}).fadeIn();
    //$('#fade').css({'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=0.99)'}).fadeIn();

    if($('#fade').length > 0) {
        $('#fade').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('<div>', { id: 'fade' })
            .appendTo('body')
            .css({'filter' : 'contrast(0.8)'})
            .append($('#canvas').show())
            .fadeIn();
    }

    return false;
};
```

and the `a.close, body` click event handler to be like this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.close, #fade', function() { // When click body
    $('#fade , .popup_block').fadeOut(); // They disappear
});
```

See my screen capture with it working here: http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/treejs-canvas-popup/